# selectivizr not working for nth-child(2) in IE7 and IE8

Tags: internet-explorer, selectivizr

Looking at the resulting CSS in IE developer tools a simple rule such as

```
.filter-dates .date-picker:nth-child(2)
{
    margin-left:200px;
}
```

shows up in IE as

```
UNKNOWN
   margin-left:200px;
```

We use the latest JQuery lib and according to the Selectivizr site nth-child is supported.

Anyone know where I'm going wrong?

Thanks,
Jacques

Comment: Does Selectivizr work for you with the other selectors?